# Oracle SQL Partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I use HR tables for learn Oracle SQL but I dont know  how can I add Partiton in HR tables. I know new create table or partiton but I need  to learn add to this tables.

Comment: 1. If you are learning Oracle SQL just now, then don't jump straight to partitioned tables; you have other things to learn first. 2. Don't modify HR; make copies of the HR tables in your "learning" schema and modify those copies; 3. Learn to use the documentation, together with Google. A trivial Google search can lead you to this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5C0F8D12-DDDF-42AB-B644-1880156832BC

Comment: Thank you for answer. I solved.